# Changing Dynamic TextField to Movie ClipSymbol

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, symbols, flashdevelop

Alright guys so this is probably easier than i am making it out to be but basically i have a Dynamic TextField on the Stage with an instance name of "livesText" which gets updated whenever the player losses or gains a life. But since other graphic problems are emerging i was wondering how i would go about removing it from the stage and making it, its own class Movie Clip. I know how to add it to the stage once it is converted to a Move Clip but im strugging with converting it. Right now its added like this from my main engine:

```
public var livesText:TextField;
```

Then the code that controls the lives:

```
public function updatePlayerLives():void
    {

        livesText.text = "Lives: " + playerLives;
    }
```

Then of course i have the Lives Values:

```
//Update Player lives and add 3 lives
        playerLives = 3;
        updatePlayerLives();
```

So how would i go about converting it to a symbol and access the content from inside the symbol so it will still function correctly as it is right now?

THanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what the issue is and why you need to take the clip off the stage and nest it inside of a movie clip. They're both display objects and they're both going to render the same except you're just burying the text field a layer deeper in the display list. Can you explain in more detail what this "graphics problem" is that you're having?

Comment: Sorry about that i should have explained more. I have a star background and when the stars pass the Dynamic Text on the stage they cover them as they pass to where the stars no longer look like they are in the background. I have the code of the stars set to where they will be in the background of Movie Clip objects that are added to the stage. So i wanted to remove them from the stage and add them through code that way the stars move behind the text instead of in front. Hope this was enough info.

Comment: If all you want to do is make sure the TextField stays on top of everything else, any time you add a new object to the stage, just put this code in there stage.addChild(livesText); . That's a really simple way to pull the TextField from it's current Z depth up to the top so it's above everything else.

Comment: Oh okay i thought you can only do that if its a movie clip object because i remember trying to remove the text using stage.removechil(livesText); But it gave me an error

Comment: Yeah you don't have to remove the child first. When you call addChild(someObject), someObject gets pulled from the container it's in automatically (if another one) or shifted to the top of the stack if the same container.